# Drawing Chart with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

I want to see different charts on the screen according to their chartType. I used switch-case for this. When I check my data with `console.log(itemData)`, I see that the correct data is coming. But when I try this way, I can't see the Chart on the screen. It doesn't give any error either. I will be glad if you help. Here is my code like this;

```
  function ChartDraw(PlotChartData) {
    for (const chartType in PlotChartData) {
      const identifiers = PlotChartData[chartType];
      const fetchPromises = identifiers.map((identifier) => {
        if (identifier.startsWith('meas')) {
          return fetch(`http://localhost:3001/test_meas/${identifier}`).then((response) => response.json());
        } else if (identifier.startsWith('var')) {
          return fetch(`http://localhost:3001/test_var/${identifier}`).then((response) => response.json());
        }
      });
      Promise.all(fetchPromises)
        .then((data) => {
          switch (chartType) {
            case 'Column':
              break;
            case 'Bar':
              break;
            case 'Line':
              break;
            case 'Area':
              break;
            case 'PolarColumn':
              break;
            case 'PolarBar':
              break;
            case 'Pie':
              break;
            case 'RadarArea':
              break;
            case 'Scatter':
              break;
            case 'RadarBubble':
              break;
            case 'RadarScatter':
              break;
            case 'RadarLine':
              const datasets = data.map((itemData, index) => {
                console.log(itemData)
                return {
                  label: `Dataset ${index + 1}`,
                  backgroundColor: `rgba(220, 220, 220, ${0.2 + 0.2 * index})`,
                  borderColor: `rgba(220, 220, 220, 1)`,
                  pointBackgroundColor: `rgba(220, 220, 220, 1)`,
                  pointBorderColor: `#fff`,
                  pointHighlightFill: `#fff`,
                  pointHighlightStroke: `rgba(220, 220, 220, 1)`,
                  data: itemData,
                };
              });

              return (
                <div className="chart-container">
                  <CChart
                    type="radar"
                    data={{
                      labels: ['Eating', 'Drinking', 'Sleeping', 'Designing', 'Coding', 'Cycling', 'Running'],
                      datasets: datasets,
                    }}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            case 'Pyramid':
              break;
            case 'Bubble':
              break;
            case 'Gantt':
              break;
            case 'Candlestick':
              break;
            case 'Candlestick':
              break;
            case 'HighLowClose':
              break;
            case 'HighLowOpenClose':
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
  }
```